# Time Comparison Not Working PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, compare

I am getting a time from mysql in the format of: hh:mm:ss
I need to compare it to the current time and it is not working

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM events WHERE clubID = "'.$clubID.'" ORDER BY date ASC, TIME(startTime) ASC');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $originaltime = $row['endTime'];
    $time = new DateTime($originaltime);

    if($time < time())
        mysql_query('UPDATE events SET passed="1" WHERE eventID = "'.$row['eventID'].'"');

}
```

i want the if statement to happen if the current time is already past the $time (from mysql)

Comment: You are comparing an object with the timestamp...

Comment: you could do that with a single update query, no php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to convert

```
new DateTime($originaltime)
```

to int (to seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT)), so solution should be:

```
if ($time->format('U') < time())
```

Comment: @nshah or even [`$time->getTimestamp()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php) as `DateTime::format()` returns a string which may need to be cast to an integer. However `DateTime::getTimestamp()` returns an int.